# The number of fixed points of an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $m$ and $n$ be two positive integers such that the groups $\mathbb{Z}_m$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ have no common direct factor. Then an automorphism $f$ of $\mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ is of type
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  f_1 & u \\
  v & f_2
\end{pmatrix}, \mbox{where} f_1{\in}{\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_m), f_2{\in}{\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n), u{\in}{\rm Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m), v{\in}{\rm Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}_n).$$Let $$f_1(\bar{x})=\bar{k}_1\bar{x},\, f_2(\hat{y})=\hat{k}_2\hat{y},\, u(\hat{y})=\bar{k}_3\bar{y},\, v(\bar{x})=\hat{k}_4\hat{x},$$where $$\gcd(k_1,m)=\gcd(k_2,n)=1 \mbox{ and } \frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)}\mid k_3, \frac{n}{\gcd(m,n)}\mid k_4.$$It follows that the subgroup of fixed points of $f$ coincides with the set of solutions $(\bar{x},\hat{y})\in\mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ of the system $$(S)\left\{\begin{array}{llcl}
(\bar{k}_1-\bar{1})\bar{x}+\bar{k}_3\bar{y}=\bar{0}\\
\hat{k}_4\hat{x}+(\hat{k}_2-\hat{1})\hat{y}=\hat{0}.\end{array}\right.$$Is it known a formula for the number of solutions of $(S)$ in terms of $m$, $n$ and $k_i$, $i=1,2,3,4$?

Comment: Can you use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to reduce to the case that either $u$ and $v$ are $0$ (when $m$ and $n$ are powers of different primes) or the case that $m=p^i$ and $n=p^j$ with $i\ne j$? Then it shouldn't be too hard to count the fixed points.

Comment: Yes, the counting can be reduced to the case $m=p^i$ and $n=p^j$ with $i\neq j$, but even in this case it is very difficult.